# Not been able to properly Traceroute from within EKS pod

Tags: networking, amazon-eks, traceroute

Even though internet connection is working properly, `traceroute` only shows node IP. Why?

Kubernetes version
1.21

[image]

Comment: There is no requirement for any intermediate device respond to traceroute within the timeout or even respond at all. Traceroute is really only useful in your own network when you have knowledge of the correct path and have the routers configured to send ICMP TTL expired messages.

Answer (score 2):

Set `-p 443` will result to host not to process the probe along the route. You can try `kubectl run busybox --image busybox --restart Never -it --rm -- traceroute -4 -l -v -m 30 google.com`. This command will show you the IP along the route; presumed your cluster has no network policy or subnet security group blocking the way.

Comment: You answer was very useful because I've found out that I didn't open all the required outbound ports for traceroute. When I tested with "all open" it worked perfectly. Now I just need to figure it out what ports are those.